# What is the probability than a Random Walk Agent has visited a given grid cell after N step?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

The question is this: Given a restricted random walk agent (can move up, down, left, right, with equal probabilities) starting at the origin, what is the probability of that agent visiting cell (x,y) after N time steps have passed?

Obviously, if $N < x+y$, the probability is $0$. But what about $N \geq x+y?$

Comment: Are you looking to be at $(x,y)$ after the (exactly) $N$th step; or just to have visited at least once within the first $N$ steps? Also what do you mean by "the agent cannot cross the boundary".

Comment: to have visited at least once within the first N steps. By "the agent cannot cross the boundary" , I meant it's a restricted random walk. It accounts for the boundary of the map.